# Angular - iframe, multiple random requests, google api

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, youtube-api

So I am developing this little website for my brother. I'm using Angular 4 and firebase. Usually, I test my works on chrome, this is my main browser. Recently, I deployed test version of the website on the firebase and I noticed that it's going crazy when opened in firefox. The iframe that embeds youtube video keeps refreshing and using dev tools shows that it's stuck in a loop of get and post requests. I have no idea what's going on. The thing works fine when opened in chrome.

Here's the link so you can see for youself [hosted on firebase](https://mehow-422d2.firebaseapp.com/)

Edit:

I think it's those requests:

```
VM9339 www-embed-player.js:241 GET https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Chrome seems to be blocking it, firefox doesn't.

Comment: you need to at a minimum isolate the part of your code that makes those requests and share it with us

Comment: The thing is that I do not make any requests. I just put iframe in my html and use youtube embed link in [src] attribute. That's it. Nothing in chrome, loads movie, stays like that. Firefox - loads mowie, post request, get request, and so on. Keeps refreshing.